# How come e.preventDefault is not executing on a keydown event?

Tags: javascript

I have made the form able to submit by pressing return on the keyboard or by pressing the button. However, for some reason the `e.preventDefault` won't execute and page refreshes on every submit. How can I use `e.preventDefault` with my current event? Or is there a better way? [Full codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/rNmKvpe)

What I tried:

```
// e.preventDefault not working
todoForm.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.code === 'Enter') {
        e.preventDefault();
        addButton.click();
    }
    addButton.onclick = function () {
        addTodo(input.value);
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code as a [mcve] in the question itself? Links can go down over time. Are you sure you want to indiscriminately add a listener in a listener like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple you're calling `e.preventDefault()` on your keydown event which means, when you press some key again it will not work since you are preventing it,

```
addButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  addTodo(input.value);
})

todoForm.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.code === 'Enter') {
        e.preventDefault();
    addButton.click();
    }
});
```

Or instead you can use this too:

```
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  addTodo(input.value);
})

todoForm.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.code === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
      addButton.click();
    }
});
```

Just a Quick Tip: add `cursor: pointer;` in your delete button styles and add `.delete-button:hover { background-color: tomato; }` in your css styles too, it looks better now!

Edit:

```
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodo(input.value);
});
```

Well i realised simply this will work Too! no need to add onsubmit or something just replace your code with this one, because when you press enter key the `submit` event is triggered so no need to manually add an event listener for that and no need to add event listener for Button too because that will also trigger `submit` event because it's set to do so!

Comment: I see, so two separate events and each event needs e.preventDefault. Good tips also. thanks

Comment: Exactly, `keydown` event is different with `submit` event

Comment: The last example (Edit) by itself won't work because I am using a textarea that autogrows. Hitting return just makes a new line break. That is what I tried at first. I should have mentioned that before :)

Answer (score 1):

```
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodo(input.value);
});

todoForm.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.code === 'Enter') {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTodo(input.value); // You can simply call function here itself
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah man i was just going to edit my answer with that only, Shit i am late

Comment: and brother, no need to add event listener for `keydown` because Enter key already triggers `submit` event

Comment: Please note that, the input element was an textarea

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the event is bubbling up and the submit event of your form is being called. Note that `preventDefault` only in `<form>` submit or submit button, prevent to refresh page. in other case submit event being called.

So you need to add `preventDefault` to `onsubmit` event not `keydown` event. **But** there is **easy way** to do that. Just add `onsubmit="return false"` in your html form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="task-count"></div>
    <form class="todo-form" onsubmit="return false">
        <textarea id="message-box" class="todo-input todoText" style="resize: none;" rows="1" placeholder="type a todo item"></textarea>
        <button type='submit' class="add-button">Add</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="todoList" class="todo-items"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this works as expected but why to use `onsubmit` attribute because it will stop only the submit event and will do nothing, instead you can just add an event listener on the form which will just preventDefault and also will call the addTodo Function

Comment: @StephenW Note that there is easy way to do that.  like `onsubmit="return false"` But if you want to use `preventDefault` only use it in `submit` button there is no need to use on `keyup`